# Ruby !map not changing object type

Tags: ruby

I've been working on a couple project Euler problems to help learn programming and was wondering if someone could explain this to me.

I have a string of numbers and I'm trying to find the largest product of any five in the sequence. This is what I have so far:

```
temp = series.split(//).map!{|x| x.to_i}
len = temp.length
maxprod = 1
0.upto(len-4) do |x|
    num = (temp[x] * temp[x+1] * temp[x +2] * temp[x+3] * temp[x+4])

    if num > maxprod
        maxprod = num
    end

end 

puts maxprod
```

temp[0].class returns a fixnum but, when I run the code I get an error " * : nil can't be coerced into FixNum (TypeError) "

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) returns an array. [`map!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21) returns `nil`. You are then taking that `nil` that `map!` returns and putting it into `temp`

Both of them still run the block on each element of the result of `split` but you should always use `map` when you are wanting the result to be put into a variable. It is a subtlety that can trip you up easily.

Change

```
temp = series.split(//).map!{|x| x.to_i}
```

to

```
temp = series.split(//).map{|x| x.to_i}
```

**Bonus:**

You can use the ampersand `&` and the name of the method as a symbol to pass a block into `map`.

```
temp = series.split(//).map(&:to_i)
```

**EDIT:**

Per your comments, you are still getting the error when multiplying the elements of the array. This could be because your `temp` array doesn't have as many elements as you think it does. Trying to access an array using an index it doesn't currently have anything at will result in `nil`.

```
temp = [1]
temp[0] #=> 1
temp[1] #=> nil
temp[0] * temp[1] #=> TypeError: nil can't be coerced into FixNum
```

You mentioned that using `temp[1].to_i` fixed this. That is because `nil` can be converted to an integer.

```
nil.to_i #=> 0
```

I would check the results of `temp` to make sure it contains what you think it contains.
You might also want to look into [Enumerable#each_slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) which takes a subset of an array and processes it in a block.

```
nums = %w{08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08}.map(&:to_i)
nums.each_slice(4) {|a| puts a.inject(:*)}
```

Comment: To extend this, the ruby paradigm is that destructive methods (methods which change the internal state of an object) tend to have a ! suffix.  In your case, map! indicates that it modifies the internal structure of whatever enumerable object you are referencing, whereas map creates a new, altered object from the original and returns it.

Comment: I made the change and I'm still receiving the same error. I did change the loop to "temp[x].to_i * temp[x+1].to_i ..." and that seemed to work (just seems repetitive).

Comment: That could be because `temp` didn't hold as many elements as you thought it would. Note that if an array only has 1 element, `temp[1] == nil`. Hence, `temp = [1]; temp[0] * temp[1]` will give you the error you got. The reason `to_i` worked for you is because `nil.to_i == 0`

Comment: Thanks for the help and thorough explanation.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell `map!` returns `nil`. I couldn't understand your statement.

Comment: @RubyLovely Sorry. I have gotten into the habit of putting a `#` in front of method names in documentation I've been writing. I'll change it to the normal expected syntax. =)

Comment: But how `!map` returns `nil` ? i never heard about it.

Comment: @RubyLovely It was probably a typo in MattLock's original question. I'm sorry but I can't join chat. I am currently at work where the feature is blocked.